# How to provide idle session time out in spring boot application using oauth

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I need to provide security to my spring boot application so i used OAUTH, but how to set idle session time out?

Example : if the user is logged in access token generated, based on access token every request authorized , but when the access token is expires user again need to login, to over come this process i want to set idle expire time out in my spring boot application.

Thanks In advance..

Comment: Doing this will make oauth useless since your session id is then longer (always if your session never times out) valid so its pointless that the access token expires. An attacker just needs your session to get as much access tokens as he/she wants.
Use the refresh token to get a new access token

Comment: @dur I think he wants to increase the session time out of the authorization server.

Comment: Yes, Yes and Yes/No. It is a duplicate but you can configure the session time out for spring boot not only for the web server.

Comment: @dur Here what I am facing issue is if I set expire time out of access token to 60 seconds then the user able to send the request for 60 seconds but here I cant set expire time, if the user is still accessing then how could I send request after 60 seconds??

Comment: @YannicKlem, yes that's what I want